# React JS - is there a way to have a variable number of checkboxes in a React UI?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, checkbox

I've written a simple application in React-js/Spring boot which essentially generates software licenses (an xml file) and records basic facts about the license issued, such as customer name etc.

This has worked fine, but now the request is to store specific features of the software which are enabled via the license, e.g. reporting, notifications, etc.

These attributes are carried as name/value pairs in the xml file, most of which will never change. But there are a few that could change, and the request is to have checkboxes on the UI which allow the user to enable one or more of this small subset of features.

Since this list of features could vary over time, I'd like to create a text file which lists the names of these features. This file would then be used as the basis to dynamically create checkboxes on the UI.

This sound like it should be do-able, but as I'm not very familiar with React, I'm wondering if this is a little ambitious.

So the question is - can you create checkboxes on a React UI based on names you read from a file?

Comment: I think you should simplify your problem as currently it stands is _very_ broad and may be opinionated. Can you read data from a file? If so, can you get that data to the client? If so, can you iterate over that data in React? The answer to all three is yes, but each one would be more on-topic as a separate question _if you are running into problems_ implementing them.

Comment: The answer to all 3 questions is yes. I have set up 3 configurable drop-boxes using this technique. However, my uncertainty is if I can create separate controls  (maybe an array of checkboxes?) as opposed to a simple list. I can't jump into implementing it as I have to create an estimate first to get the go-ahead, thus my question.